# Showing a running "time since" for every row of a mysql table on a wbpage

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have now a table in mysql that I push out every 3:rd second but I will try to push it out only when the table is updated. I use node.js for this but my first priority now is to have a "time since added at the end of the row for each record that I show (max 20 records). 
Here is a part of my script on my server side (nodejs)

```
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    var resultsList = "";
    resultsList += "<h1>Title</h1>";
    //resultsList += "<span id=\'ct\' ></span>";
    resultsList += "<table border='1'><tr>";
    resultsList += "<font size=18>";
    resultsList += "<td width=200> Column1</td><td width=100>Column2</td><td width =200>Column3</td>";
    $.each(data.results,function(index,result){
        resultsList += "<tr>" + "<td>" + result.Column1 + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.Column3.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + result.Column2 + "</td></tr>";
    });
    resultsList += "</tr>";
    $('#container').html(resultsList);
  });
```

I have a "result" table in mysql that I easily publish on a webpage but I would like to add a "timeSinceUpdated" column at the end for every row and the time shall tick while watching the webpage. I also want to have the webpage updated without the need for the users to do a refresh in their web browsers.
What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on Stackoverflow.

The best way to handle it is AJAX.
On your page where video can be watched, you need to insert Javascript, which [will run periodically](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and submit data to ie. ticker.php

ticker.php will get id of the result table and increase the counter.

> I also want to have the webpage updated without the need for the users to do a refresh in their web browsers. What is the best approach?

jQuery. Retrieve data using Ajax and [put them on your page without reloading.](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

In my opinion, those are the simplest solutions. Note, that ticker can be misused by malice user.

Comment: Thank you for fast response. Could somebody add an example where you publish a small mysql table but at the end overey row we add timeSince column that ticks up live on the webpage?

Comment: Would also be very gald if somebody could post an example of how that webpage automatically is updated in somebodyw browser when a new record for that table arrives in the mysql table.